# Django: Model with varying fields (Entity-Attribute-Value model)

Tags: python, django, entity-attribute-value

I have the following Django model to store sparse product data in a relational database. I apologize myself for any wrong relationship in the code below (ForeignKey and/or ManyToMany might be wrongly placed, I am just playing around with Django for now).

```
class ProdCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)

class ProdFields(models.Model):
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(ProdCategory)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()

class ProdData(models.Model):
    prodid = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    fieldid = models.ManyToManyField(ProdFields)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

The idea is to store the *name*, *stock* and *price* for each product in one table and the information for each product in the (**id**, **value**) format in another table.

I do know, a priori, the fields that each product category should have. For instance, a product of type **Desktop** should have, among others, *memory size* and *storage size* as fields, whereas another product of category **Monitor** should have *resolution* and *screen size* as fields.

My question is: How do I guarantee, in Django, that each product contains only the fields for its category? More precisely, when specifying a product of category **Monitor**, how to assure that only *resolution* and *screen size* are fields in the ProdData table?

I found a similar question [Django: Advice on designing a model with varying fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610327/django-advice-on-designing-a-model-with-varying-fields), but there was no answer on how to assure the above.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Django is an excellent framework, but it is still just an abstraction over a relation database.**

What you are asking isn't efficiently possible in a relational database, so it will be tough to do in Django. Primarily, because at some point your code will need to be converted to tables.

There are basically 2 ways you can do this:

1. A `product` class with a `ManyToMany` relation to an attribute table:

   ```
   class Product(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       stock = models.IntegerField()
       price = models.FloatField()
       product_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)  eg. Monitor, desktop, etc...
       attributes = models.ManyToManyField(ProductAttribute)
   class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
       property = models.CharField(max_length=20) # eg. "resolution"
       value = models.CharField(max_length=20) # eg. "1080p"
   ```

   But, your logic around certain classes of objects having certain properties will be lost.
2. Use inheritance. Django is just Python, and inheritance is certainly possible - [in fact its encouraged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance):

   ```
   class Product(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       stock = models.IntegerField()
       price = models.FloatField()

   class Desktop(Product):
       memory_size = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       storage_size = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   class Monitor(Product):
       resolution = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       screen_size = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   ```

   Then you can do queries on all products - `Products.objects.all()` - or just Monitors - Monitor.objects.all()` - and so on. This hard codes the possible products in code, so a new product type requires a database migration, but it also gives you the ability to embed your business logic in the models themselves.

There are trade-offs to both these approaches which you need to decide, so picking is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I will take that into account on my modeling. Does the approach you propose have any drawbacks with respect to performance?